# Refresh chart in c#

Tags: c#, winforms, charts

I want to automatically refresh my chart after inputting some data from different UserControl form. My chart's DataSource is from a SQL Database that's why as you can see in the properties photo below, it has a binding source.

[Properties](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t1hKR.png)

In the form ***load*** event, I only has this code to display the current data from database:

`this.medicineStocksTableAdapter.Fill(this.pharmacy_dbDataSet.medicineStocks);`

I tried `this.pharmacy_dbDataSet.Reset();` but it's not working.

Any answers from you is very much appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried `Clear` method

Comment: @viveknuna yes, still don't get what i want

Comment: do you have access to the chart id?

Comment: Are you calling `this.medicineStocksTableAdapter.Fill(this.pharmacy_dbDataSet.medicineStocks)` everytime you want to update the data or just in the `Form.Load` event handler?

Comment: @Enigmativity I am calling it just in the Form.Load event handler. Should I call it in other event handler other than Form.Load?

Comment: @viveknuna what chart id?

Comment: I mean chart control id

Comment: @viveknuna is that from database?

Comment: @Roevic - If the data updates you need to call it.

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution, it was missing a call to the `DataBind` method.

```
this.medicineStocksTableAdapter.Fill(this.pharmacy_dbDataSet.medicineStocks);
chart1.DataBind(); //after putting this, it magically worked!
```